# defining index for sql query in php

Tags: php, sql

I have a SQL query within a PHP code.

```
$code = "SELECT children, mother FROM family WHERE childrenID = ' " . $_GET['childrenID'] . "';";
```

I get an error message saying that $_GET['childrenID'] is an undefined index.

how do I define this index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: your url should look like this: `http://localhost/sampleurl.php?childrenID=1`

Comment: it seems There is no index name  like childrenID    in $_GET method so it's throwing error

Comment: Chinito, that the correct answer. You are missing the URL parameter.

Comment: Never use user input directly in sql query

Comment: show your form code

Answer (score -1):

First check do you have any value in `$_GET['childrenID']`. If yes you may also try to write your query like

```
$chid_id = $_GET['childrenID'];
$code = "SELECT children, mother FROM family WHERE childrenID = $chid_id";
```

Hope this will help you.